# Declaring a MqttClientPersistence object causes connection failure

Tags: android, mqtt, messagebroker, paho, android-open-accessory

In te below code I am trying to create a folder for persisted data. As you see I created `private final String folder = "//temp";` and the object `persistence`. But the problem is when i run the App, i says `Connection Failed`, this message comes out from the `client connection synchronous listener`, and when I connect without the object `persistence`, every thing works fine.

Am i wrongly initializing the `folder` variable or using  `MqttClientPersistence persistence` incorrectly?

**code**:

```
private final String folder = "//temp";
private final int keepAliveInterval = 30;
private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mqtt_proj_01_layout);

        final MqttClientPersistence persistence = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(folder);  
        final MqttAndroidClient client2 = new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), serverURI, clientID,persistence);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have filesystem read/write permissions enabled for your android application?

Also the path probably wants to be application specific directory. You can get the application specific directory using something like this:

`File outputDir = context.getCacheDir();`

Comment: isnt it this permission:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />?

Comment: yes, you need that, but you can still only write to specific areas of the storage related to your application. The line of code will give you a File object that points to a writable directory

Comment: I declared this "private final File outPutDirctory = this.getCacheDir();" and should i use "outPutDirectory.createTempFile"  please let me know